# How to check if computername is part of an OU then take an action

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a quick script to check if the current hostname is in an OU then perform an action based on that result.

I am able to return the computers in the OU under the "Name" Property but when trying to match the current $env:computername it never matches with what is returned for computers in the OU.

I tried the following code.

```
$pccheck = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Computers,DC=TESTENV,DC=local" | Select Name

if ($pccheck -contains $env:computername) {
    # Do something

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Output = $wshell.Popup("Pc is eligible") 

} else {

$Output = $wshell.Popup("Not eligible")

}
```

Even though I am currently on a computer which is part of the results returned for $pccheck variable it never matches the condition of the if statement and the code proceeds to the "else" code.

For example this part of the code returns result "Userpc" as the name property. My if statement doesn't work to identify that I am on "Userpc" currently to then execute the first part of the if statement and always just executes the last part.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Computers,DC=TESTENV,DC=local" | Select Name
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what syntax is needed for the if statement condition?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Active Directory filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) to simplify your code:

```bash
$getADComputerSplat = @{
    Filter     = "name -eq '$env:ComputerName'"
    SearchBase = 'OU=Test,OU=Computers,DC=TESTENV,DC=local'
}

$pccheck = Get-ADComputer @getADComputerSplat

if ($pccheck) {
    # Do something
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $Output = $wshell.Popup('Pc is eligible')
}
else {
    $Output = $wshell.Popup('Not eligible')
}
```

You can include `SearchScope = 'OneLevel'` to search for a direct child object.